# In App Purchase is not allowed

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase, app-store

My app is in development phase I tried in app purchase in sandbox mode. But form last few days if I press purchase button it some time asked to insert my apple id password, but after that it says apple id not found. Though I can download apps with my apple id.

Sometimes it does not show ask for password, I debugged the code it always shows `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` this status.

Ii was working a few days ago.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use an Apple ID to test IAP especially if your app is not live... You need to create a sandbox test user in iTunes Connect´s user and roles section and use these credentials to test IAP.

If your normal Apple iD is set in iTunes & App Store settings log out before testing IAP.